# Installing laravel ( sh: 1: composer: not found) error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've been trying to install laravel on Ubuntu 14.04. I finished all the steps, but when try to

```
laravel new mySite
```

the following message is deployed:

```
Crafting application...
sh: 1: composer: not found
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

It's looks like some trouble with composer, but I don't know why. Composer seems to work, so, what is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: If `laravel` has some `--debug` or `-vvv` (verbosity) options, run it with that.

Comment: I tried with "laravel new -vvv mySite" and I got the exact same message. sh: 1: composer: not found

Comment: aren't you missing composer ? 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: did you install composer?

Comment: Yep... composer is installed and working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't use laravel new, but I found what was happening with composer.

Laravel 5.3 needs php5.6 or higher, otherwise will run an older laravel version. I upgrade to php5.6 with this steps: https://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

then run

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel ProjectName
```

and it's done!

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error. 
I fixed it with simple symlink.

1. locate it. Run: **# whereis composer**
   composer: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
2. then create link: # **sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer**

Thats it. All works.

Answer (score 1):

If you run composer on shell, does it run? otherwise run:

```
sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli git
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Then try again, maybe you could try the composer installation syntax:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

To be sure composer is updated to the latest version and nothing is in cache run:

```
composer self-update
composer clear-cache
```

Comment: Composer is installed... I've alredy tried to use the composer sentence, it works, but it runs laravel 5.0 and I'm trying to use larevel 5.3

Comment: The problem was that laravel needs php5.6.  Thank very much for your help!!