# laravel new sh: composer: command not found

Tags: laravel, macos, composer-php, apple-m1

The problem happens whenever I call the Laravel installer: laravel new app.

I get `sh: composer: command not found`

When I call `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel app` everything works fine.

I'm using zsh and my export paths looks as follows:

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

`export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH`

`export ZSH="/Users/konstantinkrumov/.oh-my-zsh"`

`export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`

I also have an alias for composer

`alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar`

When I run which composer I get: composer:

```
aliased to php /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar
```

So far I have tried to:

1. Move composer.phar into  /usr/local/bin/
2. Reinstalled composer
3. Changed the alias path to php /usr/local/bin/composer/composer
4. Tried making a symlink as suggested in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449638/installing-laravel-sh-1-composer-not-found-error)

non of the above seem to work

Comment: What is "the problem"? What's the command you are calling?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449638/installing-laravel-sh-1-composer-not-found-error help?

Comment: Tried before posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449638/installing-laravel-sh-1-composer-not-found-error - no success.

The problem is that when i run `new laravel app` I get `sh: composer: command not found`

Comment: What else have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: All the four points bellow. I read through the docs of composer as well as laravel and the laracast forum. Tried all of these: 

[Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/sh-composer-command-not-found)
[Stackoverflow](https://github.com/pantheon-systems/terminus-build-tools-plugin/issues/165)

I have also tried to make chmod 755 on the usr/local/bin/composer folder - no luck there

Comment: What do you mean by folder? `/usr/local/bin/composer` should be a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/composer.phar` (or wherever that PHAR is placed), and not any folder

Comment: I moved the `composer.phar` from `/usr/local/bin/composer` to `/usr/local/bin/` and then ran `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` There is no effect. Still when I run `laravel new test` I get `sh: composer: command not found`

Comment: I know this is old but thought I'd add this: the reason this is happening is because most of us Mac users are using zshell, but the Laravel installer is using a straight linux shell...hence the "sh" at the start of the error line. In fact, if you enter just "sh" to enter a shell, then run "composer" you'll get the same error. A simple linux shell does not use your .zshrc file for ref. I haven't tested it but if you create an /etc/rc.local file and point to composer in there, then reboot, the system should read it after it enter multi-user run level. Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

The best solution which I was able to find was to make a function in the `~/.zshrc` file.

Function looks like this:

```
ln() {
    composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel $1;
}
```

This way I can run `ln app` and generate a new laravel app with a shorter syntax.

I was unable to figure out why running `laravel new app` gave the following output: `sh: composer: command not found` and failed to generate a new app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **macOS**, You can do:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
mv composer.phar composer
sudo chmod +x composer
```

Comment: Same result. When I run `laravel new test` then I get `sh: composer: command not found`